# Postgres jsonb_object_keys limiting result set

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-11

Can someone explain to me why `jsonb_object_keys` can limit my result set?

I would expect the following to return 2 rows:
1,3
2,`null`

But the last one is filtered out.

```
     SELECT
 idx,
        jsonb_object_keys(json_data::jsonb -> '2')
 FROM
     (
     SELECT 1 as idx, '{"1":"val","2":{"3": "val"}}' as json_data
         UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 as idx, '{"1":"val"}' as json_data
     ) a
```

Version: PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit

Comment: `jsonb_object_keys` is a set-returning function and returns no result when called on `NULL`.

Comment: What would you expect from `{"2": {"a":1, "b":2}}`?

Comment: @Bergi this should return 2 rows one with "a" and one with "b" right?

Comment: Yes. And `{"2": {}}` will return no rows. Just like `{}` will.